# Error when show Gif in UIImageView

Tags: swift, uiimageview, animated-gif

I have this code:

```
var url : NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("lambaavent2", withExtension: "gif")!
var testImage = UIImage.animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData(NSData(contentsOfURL: url))
self.cityImageView.animationImages = testImage.images
self.cityImageView.animationDuration = testImage.duration
self.cityImageView.image = testImage.images.lastObject()
self.cityImageView.startAnimating()
```

When i starting project, i get error: ‘[AnyObject] does not have a member named ‘lastObject’

What me do?

Comment: Just a guess: `animatedImageWith...` returns likely an optional. So you should unwrap `testImage!.images.lastObject()`

Comment: Try removing the trailing ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.cityImageView.image = testImage!.images!.last as? UIImage
```